# subset a python dataframe by conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I trying to select the name row with count>250, which is called effective here. So we will try to find the mean of its rate

```
t3=dfnew.groupby('name')['ratings']
t4=t3.count()
t5=t4[t4.values>250]
t6=t3.mean()
t6[(t6.index==t5.index)]
```

Obviously the problem is in last row of my code. Where I want to match t6's index with t5's index. If they match, then save it, otherwise left it out. It is kind of like inner join in SQL.

What should I do to modify last row?

Suppose dataframe like this

```
input:
name ratings
    A  1
    A  2
    :
    A  251
    B  1
    B  2
    :
    B  230
```

so intended result should be 126 ( (1+251)/2))

```
Output
A  126
```

Comment: Since you already found another way to solve your question, I just give you a short explanation of your issue: `the two indices have different length.`

Answer (score 0):

```
t3=dfnew.groupby('name')['ratings'].agg(['count','mean'])

t5=t3[t3['count']>250]
t5
```

It works fine when I aggregate two functions at the same time.